# How to install OpenStack with Swift?

Tags: 12.04, cloud, openstack

How can we install `Swift` in `OpenStack` while in `DevStack` there are lots of errors while installing via `DevStack` with enabling `Swift`

Is there any scripted installation method? Any links?